Movie or TV movie where a woman accidentally pours a potentially dangerous germ down the drain
I saw a movie or TV movie on TV in 1983 or earlier. It was in English. It was in color. So I'm sure it was made in the 1970s or early 1980s.
It was about a woman who accidentally pours a weakened but dangerous bacteria or virus down the drain. Her boss wants to cover up the incident. She wants to warn people of the potential threat. When she goes public with the accident, she is fired. The boss claims she is being fired for the accident, but it is clear she is being fired for going public. Her husband or boyfriend or father stands up in front of a bunch of people in a park or in front of a building and starts yelling things like "All hail {whatever the name of the boss was}! He is a God!" If I could remember the boss's name I'm sure I could find the movie.

Your description has echoes of Silkwood (1983)

A very good movie I saw about 30 years ago, but not the movie I'm describing. Thanks for the suggestion.

On the chance that you might be mis-remembering some details...
Erin Brockovich tells the true story of how an "unemployed single mother becomes a legal assistant and almost single-handedly brings down a California power company accused of polluting a city's water supply."
The movie does not match your description exactly, but this plot description from Wikipedia seems kind of similar to your description:
"Erin is given files for a real-estate case where Pacific Gas and Electric (PG&E) is offering to purchase the home of Hinkley, California, resident Donna Jensen. Erin is surprised to see medical records in the file and visits Donna, who explains that she had simply kept all her PG&E correspondence together. Donna appreciates PG&E's help: she has had several tumors and her husband has Hodgkin's disease, but PG&E has always supplied a doctor at their own expense. Erin asks why they would do that, and Donna replies, "because of the chromium". Erin begins digging into the case and finds evidence that the groundwater in Hinkley is seriously contaminated with carcinogenic hexavalent chromium, but PG&E has been telling Hinkley residents that they use a safer form of chromium. After several days away from the office doing this research, she is fired by Ed until he realizes that she was working all the time, and sees what she has found out."


No, I saw that movie as well. It was quite good, but it is not the movie I'm asking about and it came out in 2000. The movie I'm asking about was made in the early 80s at the latest.
